# Split Dataframe from back to front

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Somebody know how to make a split from back to front, 
when I make a split like

```
dfgeo['geo'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

I have:

```
1,2,3,4,nan,nan,nan
```

but I want

```
nan,nan,nan,4,3,2,1
```

thanks peopleee :)

Comment: `print(dfgeo['geo'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: list(reversed(x))))` ?

Comment: @Rakesh, you are missing the expand requirement. replace `.apply(lambda x: list...)` with `.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(reversed(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking to reverse the column order you can do this:

```
new_df = dfgeo['geo'].str.split(',', expand=True)
new_df[new_df.columns[::-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list(reversed(dfgeo['geo'].str.split(',',expand=True)))
```

Assuming your code returns a list!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with `::-1` for swap order of columns:

```
dfgeo = pd.DataFrame({'geo': ['1,2,3,4', '1,2,3,4,5,6,7']})
print (dfgeo)
             geo
0        1,2,3,4
1  1,2,3,4,5,6,7

df = dfgeo['geo'].str.split(',',expand=True).iloc[:, ::-1]
#if necessary set default columns names
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
print (df)

      0     1     2  3  4  5  6
0  None  None  None  4  3  2  1
1     7     6     5  4  3  2  1
```